# Doctrine ORM: Como cadastrar várias vezes na mesma tabela usando beginTransaction()

Tags: php, doctrine-2, transações

Como faço para cadastrar em uma mesma tabela do banco de dados usando o beginTransaction().
Exemplo: Cadastrar vários detalhes de um produto

```
   $entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
   try { 
      ...
      // ultimo id Produto cadastrado
        $ultimo_id = $table->getId()

        $num = array(5,2,3);
        $lote = array(8,6,7);

     // O PROBLEMA é que só cadastra a última (no caso chave [2]). Não entendi
        $this->mais_produto($num[0], $lote[0], $ultimo_id);
        $this->mais_produto($num[1], $lote[1], $ultimo_id);
        $this->mais_produto($num[2], $lote[2], $ultimo_id);

      $entityManager->getConnection()->commit();

      return true;
   }

   } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $entityManager->getConnection()->rollback();
            throw $e;
            return false;

    }
```

dasNa função mais_produto() estar rodando as funções do Doctrine $entityManager->persist($table);        $entityManager->flush();

Comment: O que a função `mais_produto` faz?

Comment: grava dados no banco, usando persist() e flush()

Comment: Não estava gravando porque eu estava rodando dentro de um array. A solução foi usar o `$entityManager->clear` depois do commit.